# MySQL upgrade from 5.6 to 8.0

Tags: mysql, upgrade

When trying to start MySQL 8.0 it complained about partially upgraded DD. Furthermore, it complained about not being to open a table S/AD.ibd which no longer exists there because we moved it to S/AD.ibd. We reverted back to MySQL 5.6 and it seems to be running fine now. It looks like it failed during converting the .frm files into the information_schema, and I suppose this is why we were able to revert back to 5.6.

My questions:

1) Does anyone have any idea what this could be?
2) Are there MySQL diagnostic tools I can run against our 5.6 instance to see if there is inconsistent state stored about our AD.ibd table?

Here is the full log if it's of interest:

> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
>   2018-06-22T15:02:56.236394Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 1831
>   2018-06-22T15:02:58.482400Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011014] [Server] Found partially upgraded DD. Aborting upgrade and deleting all DD tables. Start the upgrade process again.
>   2018-06-22T15:02:58.864512Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>   2018-06-22T15:02:58.864621Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>   2018-06-22T15:03:00.755015Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
>   2018-06-22T15:06:15.015157Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 2225
>   2018-06-22T15:06:17.585241Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
>   2018-06-22T15:06:17.585309Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
>   2018-06-22T15:06:17.585330Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012216] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './S/AD.ibd' OS error: 71
>   2018-06-22T15:06:17.585354Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012019] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `LD/AD` because it could not be opened.
>   2018-06-22T15:06:18.511449Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010727] [Server] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
>   2018-06-22T15:06:18.627162Z 2 [Warning] [MY-010772] [Server] db.opt file not found for S database. Using default Character set.
>   mysqld: /export/home/pb2/build/sb_0-28122056-1523171044.09/rpm/BUILD/mysql-8.0.11/mysql-8.0.11/sql/dd/upgrade/table.cc:1076: bool dd::upgrade_57::add_triggers_to_table(THD*, TABLE*, const String_type&, const String_type&): Assertion `t->
>   get_event() >= t_type && (t->get_event() > t_type || t->get_action_time() >= t_time)' failed.
>   15:06:19 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
>   This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
>   or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>   or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>   Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
>   As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
>   collection process might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `/` (or certain other things that could confuse the file manager) in a table name.

Perhaps you can rename it?

**Update**

OK, `S` is the database name, `AD` is the table name.

No, you cannot move `.ibd` files around.  There is critical information in `ibdata1` that will get confused.

It is possible to do

```
RENAME TABLE X.AD TO Y.AD
```

(At least that was possible before 8.0.  The internals of 8.0 are radically different; if such a cross-db `RENAME TABLE` fails, file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com )

Comment: S is the schema and A is the table name. I could rename it in the L schema but i'm still not sure why MySQL thinks table A still exists in the S schema. I was hoping there were diagnostic tools I could run against the MySQL instance which would shed some light on what is going on. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Aha.  I updated my Answer.

Comment: I'll try running the RENAME statement and see if the error still appears when trying to upgrade from 5.6 to 8.0. In the meantime, I'll also test out the two back-up strategies we discussed here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210524/reversion-strategy-when-upgrading-mysql